# python ctypes cdll function by name isn't working instead of ordinal

Tags: python, ctypes, dllimport

I'm loading a dll with `ctypes.cdll()` and I don't have access to the function names:

```
foo = cdll.LoadLibrary("my.dll")
foo.myfunction() #AttributeError
foo[52]() #works as expected
```

Right now I'm using a program called [dll export viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net) to find the ordinal for each function call, but I'm worried that when the dll changes the ordinals will change with it.

This is cdll and when inspected I don't see any mangled names; everything looks as it should.  Besides getting the names wrong, what else could be preventing python from loading the function names?

Comment: If you get the function names right, exactly as they are exported, and displayed by any PE function export viewer, you will be able to load them. If ctypes gives you attribute error, that means you got the function name wrong.

Comment: [DLL Export Viewer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/dll_export_viewer.html) shows you the list of exported names. If the DLL exports a function named "bar", access it as `foo.bar`.

Comment: I'm using the exact name as shown in the DLL export viewer.  The names contain upper case, lower case, and the underscore character.

Comment: Seems like the DLL export viewer tool undecorates the function names.  ```dumpbin /exports foo.dll``` shows decorated names :/

Comment: If the DLL only has a C++ API, you can try to wrap it with Cython, Boost.Python or SWIG -- but you'll need a C++ compiler in that case.